Работает ли SELinux в режиме enforcing на виртуальных машинах
Я пытаяюсь установить SELinux на виртуальную машину с Ubuntu 23.10, но после изменения конфига с permissive на enforcing и перезапуска машины, ВМ перестаёт запускаться. В чём может быть проблема? Инструкцию использовал отсюда. Использую VBox 7.0.14 с гостевыми дополнениями.
